# Scikit's GBM assumptions on feature type

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Does scikit's GradientBoostingRegressor make any assumptions on the feature's type? Or does it treat all features as continuous? I'm asking because I have several features that are truly categorical that I have encoded using LabelEncoder().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All features are continuous for gradient boosting (and practically all other estimators).

Tree-based models should be able to learn splits in categorical features that are encoded as "levels" (1, 2, 3) rather than dummy variables ([1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]), but this requires deep trees instead of stumps and the exact ordering may still affect the outcome of learning.